# How to link google account to local account for google oauth2 login

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, grails-plugin, google-oauth

I wanted to switch to **Google for Spring Security OAuth plugin** from the normal username and password login . I have gone as far as letting the user login with Google and retrieve his email-address and user-name.I already have email-address as one of my entity in user table ,so how can i match the email I got from his login to the one on my domain to identify the user for spring.

Answer (score 0):

The best way it's create domain that will be associate UserConnection with User. For example it will be SocialAccount. After user will login by Google+ you just need to check if exist SocialAccount for this UserConnection if yes - so you have a user, if no - create a new one
For example domain model maybe

```
class SocialAccount {
   static belongsTo = [fan: Fan, connection: UserConnection]
}
```

and you should to update User class:

```
class User {
  static hasMany = [accounts: SocialAccount]
}
```

Hope it will be helpful